# No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-starter

I am using spring starter-email service to send emails to the users when there will be new job posting: I am following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-sending-email-via-smtp/) article from geeks for geeks, I feel issue is something with @Value annotation, but unable to get it
but while running mvn-clean install, I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobController' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\controller\JobController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobService' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\service\JobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\service\EmailService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132) ~[spring-boot-test-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobService' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\service\JobService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\service\EmailService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailService' defined in file [C:\Users\ViShah\IdeaProjects\avatureJobSearch\target\classes\com\avature\service\EmailService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Below is my email service

```
import com.entity.Job;
import com.entity.User;
import com.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmailService {

    @Value(value = "${spring.mail.username}")
    String sender;
    final String HOST = "http://localhost:8080/";
    UserRepository userRepository;
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendEmailWithDetails(Job job){
        List<User> usersList = null;
        if(!job.getPreferredSkills().isEmpty())
            usersList = userRepository.findBySkills(job.getPreferredSkills());
        else{
            usersList = userRepository.findAll();
        }
        for(User user: usersList){
            try {
                generateEmailBodyAndSend(job, user);
            }catch (MessagingException e){
                log.error("error while sending mail to user:"+user.getEmail());
            }
        }
    }

    private void generateEmailBodyAndSend(Job job, User user ) throws MessagingException {
        String body = "<h4>Hey, Found new matching job for you</h4>\n <a href="+HOST+job.getId()+">"+job.getTitle()+"</a>";
        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
        helper.setText(body, true);
        helper.setSubject("Notification");
        helper.setFrom(sender);
        helper.setTo(user.getEmail());
        log.info("sending mail to:"+user.getEmail());
        javaMailSender.send(msg);
        log.info("sent mail to:"+user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

I am using spring-boot 2.7.0 and spring-starter-email 2.7.1
below is my application.properties file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/jobDB
kafka.bootstrapAddress=localhost:9092
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=testingmynotification@gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you post your application.properties file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the Lombok constructor won't contain the `@Value` annotation. Rather, it will look like this:

```java
public EmailService(String sender, UserRepository userRepository, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

Due to this, Spring doesn't know how to pass the `sender` field, and so it complains that there's no bean of type `String`.

The solution is to write your own constructor:

```java
// Add the @Value to the sender parameter
public EmailService(@Value(value = "${spring.mail.username}") String sender, UserRepository userRepository, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

After that, you can remove the `@Value` annotation from the `sender` field (since it's on the constructor) and remove the `@AllArgConstructor` annotation.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an alternative way to solve this problem. This solution doesn't require writing your own constructor.

The `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation gathers all class fields (the exception is initialized `final` field). Based on your code, Lombok will generate a constructor like below.

```
public EmailService(String sender, UserRepository userRepository, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

As the `sender` is not a bean but only a value wired from properties, the container won't be able to find it as a bean.

Similar annotation - `@RequiredArgsConstructor` gathers **only** non-initialized `final` fields.

To resolve your issue, you should refactor the code like below:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmailService {

    @Value(value = "${spring.mail.username}")
    String sender;

    final String HOST = "http://localhost:8080/";

    final UserRepository userRepository;
    final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    ...
}
```

Now your constructor will look like this:

```
public EmailService(UserRepository userRepository, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

Note that `final` fields are required to be initialized before the constructor completes and you are not able to reassign them after. As long as you don't need to change repository and sender in runtime, these fields **should** be `final`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the Lombok annotation @AllArgsConstructor and the Spring annotation @Value on a field in the same time without additional actions.
If you want to do it:

1. Create "lombok.config" file in the root directory of the project;
2. Add next lines to the lombok.config file:

config.stopbubbling = true

lombok.copyableannotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value